# Cannot establish connection outside of the local -Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, socket.io, firewall

server.js

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const io = new Server(8000);

io.on("connect", (socket) => {
    console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);

    socket.on("ping", (cb) => {
        console.log("ping");
        cb();
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log(`disconnect ${socket.id}`);
    });
});
```

client.js

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

var  socket = io.connect('ws://<server-ip>:8000', {transports:['websocket']});

socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);
});

setInterval(() => {
    const start = Date.now();
    socket.emit("ping", () => {
        console.log(`pong (latency: ${Date.now() - start} ms)`);
    });
}, 1000);



socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => console.log(`Socket disconnected: ${reason}`));
socket.on("close", (reason) => console.log(`Socket closed: ${reason}`));
socket.on('error', (data) => console.log(`WS Error: ${data}`));
socket.on('connect_error', (data) => console.log(`Connect Error: ${data}`));
```

Im not able to establish connection over different internet, it works fine over local.
Also tried to turn off the firewall and still same result,i dont know what am i missing ?
Using socketio v4 for server and client

Comment: if you have express try triggering any rest from outside of your network to see if it is a general configuration problem not specific to socket.io

Comment: Fetched the same issue. Solution -> Try adding ssl certificate to make the server secure and then use ```wss://<server-ip>:port```. should work.

Comment: it not website just will be backend service

Comment: Do you host your backend somewhere? Or do you try to access it on your local PC from the outside internet?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yeah im running the server in local and trying to acces it to outside local internet

Comment: You would need to open ports in your router and redirect traffic to your PC. Also, you would need to have a public IP address which isn't always the case, you have to ask your internet provider about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 hours struggling with windows, solved by using aws ec2 linux2 in 30 minutes i see windows not good such as like theese stuffs (even though i did port forwarding and other customizations). Here is the solution who ever want to make the server public.

1. Rent aws ec2 or aws lightsail (i did over lightsail to not waste time both same)
2. Configure the inbound rules as Custom->TCP->Port->White List (for socket)
3. Configure linux dependencies
4. And clone the repo and run the server

Suggestion: Dont use windows for mental health

U can use server/client example above, works fine.

Thanks for helping @KonradLinkowski @nosTa @SayeedAfridi